# substitute a character from one script to another

Tags: xetex, cross-referencing, characters, arabic, xr

I am working in XeLaTeX + Memoir, and I have two documents: one typeset in English and another typeset in Arabic. As the two documents are related, I am using the package `xr` to establish cross-references between the two. My Arabic text is using eastern Arabic (so-called Arabic-Indic) numerals. When `xr` pulls in the page number of the cross-reference from the Arabic Document into my English Document, the number displayed is an Arabic-Indic ١.

What I would like is for this to be presented instead as a (regular) Arabic number as used in English: 1. Obviously these are two different characters, with different glyphs. The font I am using, Khaled Hosny's excellent Amiri, contains both (though at a later stage, the English text will be typeset in a different Latin font).

Thus, my question is how can I replace/substitute one character (1) for another (١), assuming the font contains both?

Here are the MWE files (for `xr` to work, you must compile the first one, then the second one, then recompile the first one again):

### minimalxr1.tex

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=OldStyle,Ligatures=Common]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,WordSpace=1.66]{Amiri}

\externaldocument{minimalxr2}

\begin{document}

This is a test of cross-referencing to this page \pageref{test}.

\end{document}
```

### minimalxr2.tex

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=mashriq]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Ligatures=TeX,Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,WordSpace=1.66]{Amiri}

\externaldocument{minimalxr1}

\begin{document}

\begin{Arabic}

هذا أنموذج 
\label{test}

\end{Arabic}

\end{document}
```

Comment: NB: I have played around with things like catcode definitions which make one character expand into another: but because I am not actually typing in the Arabic ١, but it is rather being pulled in through the `XR` package, this has no effect. I also tried with `\XeTeXinterchartokenstate` but wasn't able to get it to work (due most likely to my inexperience).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need Arabic in `minimalxr1.tex`, you can use `\newunicodechar` as follows. Language tests could be added.

### `minimalxr1.tex`

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\newunicodechar{١}{1}
\newunicodechar{٢}{2}
\newunicodechar{٣}{3}
\newunicodechar{٤}{4}
\newunicodechar{٥}{5}
\newunicodechar{٦}{6}
\newunicodechar{٧}{7}
\newunicodechar{٨}{8}
\newunicodechar{٩}{9}
\newunicodechar{٠}{0}


\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=OldStyle,Ligatures=Common]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,WordSpace=1.66]{Amiri}

\externaldocument{minimalxr2}

\begin{document}

This is a test of cross-referencing to this page \pageref{test}.

Also \pageref{2},
\pageref{3},
\pageref{4},
\pageref{5},
\pageref{6},
\pageref{7},
\pageref{8},
\pageref{9},
\pageref{10}

\end{document}
```

### `minimalxr2.tex`

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=mashriq]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Ligatures=TeX,Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,WordSpace=1.66]{Amiri}

\externaldocument{minimalxr1}

\begin{document}

\begin{Arabic}

هذا أنموذج 
\label{test}

\end{Arabic}

\newpage
x\label{2}

\newpage
x\label{3}

\newpage
x\label{4}

\newpage
x\label{5}

\newpage
x\label{6}

\newpage
x\label{7}

\newpage
x\label{8}

\newpage
x\label{9}

\newpage
x\label{10}

\end{document}
```

### `minimalxr1.pdf`

[image]